# Al asignar un retorno de valores el cual devuelve 2 enteros, a 2 variables globales me sale: "TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object"

Tags: python

Defino esta función que debería devolver 2 enteros con los nombres "digNum" y "MXADIVINANZAS".

```
    def elegirDificultad():
    dificultad = ''
    while dificultad not in '1 2 3 4'.split():
        print('¿Qué dificultad deseas jugar? (Fácil"1"/Normal"2"/Dificil"3"/Extremo"4") (escribe el número correspondiente)')
        dificultad = input()
        print(dificultad)
        if dificultad == 1:
            digNum = 3
            MXADIVINANZAS = 15
            return digNum, MXADIVINANZAS
        if dificultad == 2:
            digNum = 3
            MXADIVINANZAS = 10
            return digNum, MXADIVINANZAS

        if dificultad == 3:
            digNum = 4
            MXADIVINANZAS = 10
            return digNum, MXADIVINANZAS

        if dificultad == 4:
            digNum = 4
            MXADIVINANZAS = 5
            return digNum, MXADIVINANZAS
```

Al intentar asignarlos a estas dos variables me da un error.

```
    digitosNum, MAXADIVINANZAS = elegirDificultad()
```

Comment: ¿Está bien indentado tu código?

Comment: Concepto: Python NO devuelve múltiples valores como erroneamente muchos enseñan. Cuando se colocan multiples variables separadas por coma python automaticamente las convierte a tupla. En el llamado a la función puedes colocar una sola variable (a la que se asignará la tupla), o un numero de variables iguales a la cantidad de valores de la tupla y python desempacará la tupla retornada, asignando un valor a cada variable.

Comment: No hace falta usar `split` en el `while`, una cadena ya es iterable y puedes hacer `while dificultad not in '1234'`. También en vez usar varios `if` puedes usar un `if` y el resto `elif` así no se evaluará el resto si una anterior se cumple y en vez de poner un `return` en cada condición solo pon un `retutn` al final de todo

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un error aquí:

```
    dificultad = input()
    print(dificultad)
    if dificultad == 1:
```

La variable `dificultad` contiene una cadena ("1") y la estas comparando contra un entero (1).

Se parecen, pero no son lo mismo.

Entonces, cuando intentas iterar por segunda vez, la expresión

```
dificultad not in '1 2 3 4'.split()
```

se reduce a

```
'1' not in ['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

qué es `False`, por lo que se sale del `while` y se termina la función sin retornar ninguna valor, o sea, retorna `None`.

*Solución*

Lo más sano es cambiar todos los `if`, por

```
    dificultad = input()
    print(dificultad)
    if dificultad == "1":
```

¿Por qué no convertir la entrada a entero? Pues porque la entrada puede ser cualquier cosa, y si no es un entero, entonces se genera una excepción.